# Magento 2 Error: Product disappeared on frontend, one store view only

Tags: magento2, frontend, products, index

**We are having a weird problem since some days after the shop running for months without trouble.**

On one day *(only thing we did were some backup-operations on the database which might have caused this)*,

- suddenly all product disappeared on frontend, showing "Wir können keine Produkte entsprechend dieser Auswahl finden", "we could not find any products for this selection".
- This happened on the default store view, german
- the other store views, french and english are not affected

When we open and save on **product in backend**, it sometimes **shows up** in **front-end** for some seconds.
However, they disappear again with each indexer run.

Another point: After resignation yesterday evening, the products "just" have been back this morning. I don't know what indexer run made them disappear some time later.

Magento 2.1.13, managed server

**Anyone has an idea or help for this issue -and probably broken database?**

What we did until now:

- reindexed many times, cleared and flushed cache
- saved many products in top- and store view
- saved category in top- and store view
- deleted the flat tables in database, reindexed

No effect on all.

What we did not do until now is setup:upgrade and rebuild the production static files because we are experiencing a php-problem on the development site on the same server. We want to avoid that we could end up with a non-productive site after that due to the php problem.

Comment: Did you look around that all `product_id` has 1 as the value of `website_id` in a table called as `catalog_product_website`?

Comment: Just checked: Each single one has "1" in this column

Answer (score 0):

As you have done a backup restore, check wether trigger were dumped or not, else check that triggers user is the same as you current magento database user.

```
mysql> show triggers
```

If you have one of these two cases, just recreate the triggers (with correct user), Reindex catalog and product will be shown again